# UIView slide down from the top?

Tags: objective-c, uiview, uiviewcontroller

I am looking at creating a slide up or down view like in Uber's app. Not sure if its simple a UIView they are sliding up over the current top view or is this an embedded view control?

Also how did they handle the settings view that splits the screen?

*Sorry no screen shots as they wouldn't do any good as you cannot see the animation.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are using a custom container controller, which has been initialized with 2 child controllers, one is the map controller and the other is the settings controller. The container controller, handles the views of both the settings and the map controllers using basic frame animations. The root controller of the container controller is the settings controller, and the mapView is presented over the Settings View. When the user taps the settings button, the map view's frame is animated such that it is partially visible and the settings view appears. The settings controller has a navigationController, which just pushes new controllers on tapping each tableView cell.

Answer (score 0):

If we're talking about uber 2.0, then I would say it's pretty easy. The top part that slides behind the map, with profiles and etc, is just a navigation controller, that doesn't take the whole screen. And you don't have to keep that background controller in memory all the time, just an image of it inside CALayer, and put that layer below your navigation controller.